# Apply command line for some files

Tags: bash, command-line, bioinformatics

I am a beginner in bash and have a problem applying a command to all the files in a folder. Here is the command in question:

```
for samples in ~/work/RADseq/Pool1_process_radtags/*
do
  /usr/local/bioinfo/src/BBMap/bbmap_38.95/reformat.sh in=$samples.1.fq in2=$samples.2.fq out=$samples-reform out2=$samples-reform2 addslash=true
done
```

This is what the contents of the file `Pool1_process_radtags` look like:

```
XY1.1.fq
XY1.2.fq
XY2.1.fq
XY2.2.fq
XY15.1.fq
XY15.2.fq
XY18.1.fq
XY18.2.fq
```

The command `in=` must take into account all files ending with `.1.fq` and `in2=` with `.2.fq`

Here is an example :

```
/usr/local/bioinfo/src/BBMap/bbmap_38.95/reformat.sh in=XY1.1.fq in2=XY1.2.fq out=XY1.1-reform.fq out2=XY1.2-reform.fq addslash=true
```

And the same for `XY2`, `XY15` and `XY18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command

```
for samples in ~/work/RADseq/Pool1_process_radtags/*
```

will loop over all files, both `.1.fq` and `.2.fq`.

I assume you want to run the command once for every pair of `.1.fq` and `.2.fq` files and that the files always exist in pairs. That's why I change the pattern to match the `.1.fw` files only and used `${variable%pattern}` to remove this trailing part of the file name. For example, the input file `XY1.1.fq` will result in `samples="~/work/RADseq/Pool1_process_radtags/XY1"`, and the script will append trailing parts as necessary.

I also added quoting to prevent possible problems in case of file names with spaces or special characters.

```
for fw1file in ~/work/RADseq/Pool1_process_radtags/*.1.fw
do
    samples="${fw1file%.1.fw}"
    /usr/local/bioinfo/src/BBMap/bbmap_38.95/reformat.sh in="$samples".1.fq in2="$samples".2.fq out="$samples".1-reform.fq out2="$samples".2-reform.fq addslash=true
done
```

(You can use https://www.shellcheck.net to find errors in shell scripts.)